# How to get full date with full month name like 02 November 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, date-format

I want to load date to the text box with full month, this means that the users will get the current date and time every time they want to save the date on the text box. They won't write anything

Here is the format i want "*02 November 2015*" but am not getting what am looking for. I got this results "DD-NOV-2015" and that's not what am looking for.

Should you know any simple way i can do it using j query,ajax or any,please help

Please see my code below

Page Load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtInceptiondate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("DD-MMM-yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUpper();
    }
```

Saving to the database

```
    protected void tbnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IList<tblPolicy> _Inception = _dc.tblPolicies.Where(a => a.Name == txtname.Text.ToString()).ToList();

        if (_Inception != null)
        {
            if (_Inception.Count() == 0)
            {
                tblPolicy _Policy = new tblPolicy
                {
                    Name = txtname.Text,
                    PolicyName = txtpolicyname.Text,
                    InceptionDate = txtInceptiondate.Text
                };
                _dc.tblPolicies.InsertOnSubmit(_Policy);
                _dc.SubmitChanges();
                lblresults.Visible = true;
                lblresults.Text = "Welcome " + txtname.Text + " ! , Your new policy " + txtpolicyname.Text + " is well recived!";

                txtpolicyname.Text = "";
                txtname.Text = "";
                txtInceptiondate.Text = "";
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `DD` as a custom date and time specifier. These specifiers are case sensitive. That's why it reflects itself to the result as it is.

You need to use `dd MMMM yyyy` format instead. And don't use `ToUpper` method since you want `November` not `NOVEMBER`.

```
this.txtInceptiondate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Further reading:

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [MMMM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMMM_Specifier) to get the full name of the month. Check the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). Try this:

```
this.txtInceptiondate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date;
 this.txtInceptiondate.Text = now.ToString("D");
```

It will give result in this format 02 November 2015

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I missed something stupid stuff. Deleted my comment. But still, this generates result based `CurrentCulture` settings. It _may_ night generate english based month name.