# Visual Studio Website how to get date data type without time in table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I created a simple website that shows some tables. I created a database from `App_Data` folder and created some tables. A table has a column of `AddDate` and its datatype is `date`. 
I want to get only date without time. Currently my website shows the date like this:

```
1/30/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

I want to get the date such as `Jan, 30 2017`.

Here's what I did:

I created a database named TestDB adding from App_Data.

[image]

From the database, I added a table and added a column called AddDate.
Its datatype is `date`.

[image]

I selected `data` from the datatype drop-down of the AddDate column, but I get data with time as shown above.

How do I set `date` datatype without time in table in Visual Studio?

---

Update: 6/11

I could get only date by adding `{0:d}` in the property of the grid view. 
[image]

[image]

For reference:
[BoundField.DataFormatString Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: If I got it right, you can cast your date to string like this: `string date = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: @hassan.ef I just added a picture of the datatype drop-down. I created a table using a database. In this case, can I use the code you provided? If so, where do I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slight disconnect between the database layer and the C# code layer logic that we all have to deal with from time to time, in C# `DateTime` is used for values that are DateOnly and those that carry a time as well.

When storing these values in SQL we can choose to use a `Date` data type and the time information will simply be omitted.

In your code you can use the `.Date` property to ignore the time component and return a date value that has a zero (midnight) time value.

So we accept that the runtime data type to use is `DateTime` now the only concern is how to render the value in the format that you have requested.

The DateTime datatype has a [.ToString(string format)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring) method that can be used at the point that you need to visualise the value.

```
var formattedDate = dateValue.ToString("MMM, dd yyyy");
```

If you are using Entity Framework or nHibernate ORM Frameworks then they have in built conventions for specifying that the data column data type should be a `Date` instead of a `DateTime`, but within your C# code you should use the `DateTime` data type to hold the date value.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

`var customDateFormat = yourDate.ToString("MMM, dd yyyy");`

You can look into [DateTime.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netstandard-2.0) method in order to see how you can convert a datetime in the format you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your DateTime like this:

```
  DateTime time = DateTime.Now;  // you datetime value
  DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and add using `System.Globalization;` in the top of of your class

you can also see this link:
[How to get full date with full month name like 02 November 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499432/how-to-get-full-date-with-full-month-name-like-02-november-2015)